# WEBSERVICES : How to store mal-formed XML in webservices?

Tags: java, xml, web-services

I am hosting a web service. I wanted to handle the scenario, in case the client sends a mal-formed XML

Here is the handler I have created

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc)
{
    Boolean outboundProperty =
        (Boolean)smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

    SOAPMessage message = null;
    try
    {
               // This handling iss required in case a mal-formed XML is sent.    
               message = smc.getMessage();    
    }
    catch(Throwable t ) 
    { 
          // I want to log the XML in the database
          // But the problem is I don't know how to get the XML
          // as message is null.
    }

}
```

I get to land into the catch(Throwable t) block where I have no information about the XML that was sent. 
What I can log into the error log table is just that a mal-formed XML has been sent by client.

Actual Requirement:

To log and store the malformed XML for tracking purposes.

Comment: Is this Java? What's the platform?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't `catch (Throwable t)`. Catch the Web-Service specific exception class.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code for getting the exact line number and exception in soap message for logging purposes:

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext mc) {
    try {
        final SOAPMessage message = mc.getMessage();

        String i = convertToString(message);

        System.out.println(i);

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
//            e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

This Code will take care of the any malformed SOAP Message